# How to resolve the unhandled promise rejection? I am trying to write a automation test for microsoft login page, it re-directs to other origin

Tags: cypress, unhandled-promise-rejection

I am learning cypress automation tool and have knowledge about basic concepts. So I tried to automate the Microsoft outlook login page as like normal login page but I am getting an error of "unhandled promise rejection".

My code looks like below,

```
it('Outlook', ()=> {
        cy.visit('https://outlook.office.com/mail/')
            cy.get('#i0116').clear().type('hello@gmail.com')
            cy.get('#idSIButton9').click()
            cy.get('#3i0118').clear().type('Password@123')
            cy.get('#idSIButton9').click()   
    })

I tried adding the below code but I couldn't resolve the issue,

Cypress.on('uncaught:exception',(err,runnable,Promise)=>{
    if(Promise){
        return false
    }
})
```

Error description:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As it's suggested in the [documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/end-to-end-testing/writing-your-first-end-to-end-test#Step-1-Visit-a-page), you shouldn't use applications that you don't control. So try to run an application locally and write tests for it. For example: [Cypress applications](https://docs.cypress.io/examples/examples/applications#Kitchen-Sink) or download example of [Angular Tour of Heroes app.](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt0)